# How do i stop AHK loop when LButton is up

Tags: autohotkey

I just want this loop to work when LButton is down and stop when LButton is up.I 
The code works when LButton is down but it continues working when i lift my finger off the left click button.

```
 mem:=0
~*LButton:: 
Sleep, 100
KeyWait, LButton, T0.10
If ErrorLevel = 1
   {
   While GetKeyState("LButton","P")

Loop {
GetKeyState, state, LButton, P
    If state = U
        Break

 MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos

 if (xpos > mem)          ;moved right
    {
     send, {a down}         ;send key
     mem:=xpos
    }
 else
     send, {a up}

 if (xpos < mem)          ;moved left
    {
     send, {d down}
     mem:=xpos
    }
 else
     send, {d up}

  Sleep, 100
}
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You case is very similar to the example of the usage of the [while loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/While.htm).
If you look at that you can see, you don't need the Loop inside the while. Just have

```
while GetKeyState("LButton")
{
    ; Your code here:
    MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos

    if (xpos > mem)          ;moved right
    {
        send, {a down}         ;send key
        mem:=xpos
    }
    else{
        send, {a up}
    }

    if (xpos < mem)          ;moved left
    {
        send, {d down}
        mem:=xpos
    }
    else{
        send, {d up}
    }

    Sleep, 100
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, however, this script is not working for me, it just opens AHK really fast and closes.

Comment: I've left off all the stuff that came before. Try looking at the example on the link, see if that works, and go from there adding your functionality!

Comment: I did and still not working. When i activate the script and send a command to key {A} the letter {A} keeps on sending despite not clicking LButton.